# sql select tree view from object (2lvl max)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following table structure
|human_id | parent_id | name |

I need to display it like a tree. For example:

Alisa
--Robin
--Miranda
--Mark
Max
Robin
--Robert
--John

I have this select but it selects everything + joines in righter to parent 1 child

```
SELECT c1.*, c2.* 
FROM humans c1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN humans c2 ON c2.parent_id = c1.human_id
```

**I need** some links "How to make wise select only?" to select parents and their children immideately to display like in tree example

**Edit** Thx to Quassnoi, who understood what I meant and did exactly what I needed.

**Edit2** I'm using the proper way by simply selecting all and then with php function format it as a tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN parent_id IS NULL THEN name ELSE CONCAT('--', name) END name
FROM    humans
ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN parent_id IS NULL THEN human_id ELSE parent_id END,
        CASE WHEN parent_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

Comment: wooooooooooooooooow this is pure awesome!!!!